# The left hand side must be a variable (ArrayList and Array)

Tags: java, arrays, variables, arraylist

I'm a little confused between an ArrayList and an Array, I understand what a variable is but I don't understand why I can't convert the ArrayList to an Array and have the same effect.

This piece of code I currently have when using an ArrayList

```
import java.util.Objects;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;


public final class NpcDefinitionLoader extends JsonLoader {

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link NpcDefinitionLoader}.
     */
    public NpcDefinitionLoader() {
        super(DefinitionEditor.fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    @Override
    public void load(JsonObject reader, Gson builder) {
        int index = reader.get("id").getAsInt();
        String name = Objects.requireNonNull(reader.get("name").getAsString());
        String description = Objects.requireNonNull(reader.get("examine").getAsString());
        int combatLevel = reader.get("combat").getAsInt();
        int size = reader.get("size").getAsInt();
        boolean attackable = reader.get("attackable").getAsBoolean();
        boolean aggressive = reader.get("aggressive").getAsBoolean();
        boolean retreats = reader.get("retreats").getAsBoolean();
        boolean poisonous = reader.get("poisonous").getAsBoolean();
        int respawnTime = reader.get("respawn").getAsInt();
        int maxHit = reader.get("maxHit").getAsInt();
        int hitpoints = reader.get("hitpoints").getAsInt();
        int attackSpeed = reader.get("attackSpeed").getAsInt();
        int attackAnim = reader.get("attackAnim").getAsInt();
        int defenceAnim = reader.get("defenceAnim").getAsInt();
        int deathAnim = reader.get("deathAnim").getAsInt();
        int attackBonus = reader.get("attackBonus").getAsInt();
        int meleeDefence = reader.get("defenceMelee").getAsInt();
        int rangedDefence = reader.get("defenceRange").getAsInt();
        int magicDefence = reader.get("defenceMage").getAsInt();

        NPCDefinitions.definitions.get(index) = new NPCDefinitions(index, name, description, combatLevel, size, attackable, aggressive, retreats,
            poisonous, respawnTime, maxHit, hitpoints, attackSpeed, attackAnim, defenceAnim, deathAnim, attackBonus, meleeDefence,
            rangedDefence, magicDefence);
    }
}
```

I get an error here

```
NPCDefinitions.definitions.get(index) = new NPCDefinitions(index, name, description, combatLevel, size, attackable, aggressive, retreats,
        poisonous, respawnTime, maxHit, hitpoints, attackSpeed, attackAnim, defenceAnim, deathAnim, attackBonus, meleeDefence,
        rangedDefence, magicDefence);
```

Saying the left side must be a variable. When I use an Array like this

```
NPCDefinitions.definitions[index] = new NPCDefinitions(index, name, description, combatLevel, size, attackable, aggressive, retreats,
        poisonous, respawnTime, maxHit, hitpoints, attackSpeed, attackAnim, defenceAnim, deathAnim, attackBonus, meleeDefence,
        rangedDefence, magicDefence);
```

Code works perfect.

I'm confused about this, how would I make this work by using an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `List#add` instead of `List#get` and assign operator.

Try:

```
NPCDefinitions.definitions.add(index, new NPCDefinitions(index, name, description, combatLevel, size, attackable, aggressive, retreats,
    poisonous, respawnTime, maxHit, hitpoints, attackSpeed, attackAnim, defenceAnim, deathAnim, attackBonus, meleeDefence,
    rangedDefence, magicDefence));
```

**EDIT:**

`NPCDefinitions.definitions` has to defined before use.

Assign a new `ArrayList` instance to `definitions`  like`NPCDefinitions.definitions = new ArrayList<>();` somewhere before or at member definition in class `NPCDefinitions`.

Comment: I still get a java.lang.NullPointerException?

Comment: I'm edit my answer to explain how avoid the `NullPointerException`

Comment: Your wellcome. Please mark question as answered and fell free to vote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`ArrayList#set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-):

```
NPCDefinitions.definitions.set(index, new NPCDefinitions(..))
```

Note that `get` is a *method* and not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`NPCDefinitions.definitions[index]` is a variable.

`NPCDefinitions.definitions.get(index)` is a method call, so you can't assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add/set values in an ArrayList the same as in arrays.

To change the value in a specific index :

```
NPCDefinitions.definitions.set(index, new NPCDefinitions(..));
```

This is the method whose behavior is the most similar to that of an array assignment (`arr[index]=`), since it doesn't change the size of the ArrayList. However, you should note that this method will fail if the size of the ArrayList <= index.

Instead of this method, you can simply add a new value to the end of the List :

```
NPCDefinitions.definitions.add(new NPCDefinitions(..));
```